# Displaying BindingList<(int, int, int)> in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `BindingList` that is as follows:

```
var lst = BindingList<(int Count, int ProductId, int SupplierId)>
```

and I am trying to display this list in a `DataGridView`:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = lst;
```

`lst` contains a few elements and I can see the `DataSource` is being set properly when looking in the debugger. However, nothing is showing up in `dataGridView1`. From the research I've done, I think this issue is related to not having any columns. I set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `true`, but this still did not resolve this issue.

I had assumed the names of each tuple item would be taken as the column name, but now it seems that is not the case. How do I display this `BindingList` in a `DataGridView` such that each tuple item is in its own column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use value tuples in data-binding, because tuples implemented by using "fields", where Winforms data-binding works with properties.

In your particular case you should create a class with properties.

```
public class Line
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
}
```